# how to find that multiple column value is in other column value or not if not then stored in other column

Tags: python, pandas

```
                                              col1                             Col2 status        o/p value
0  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV 10713-234-NODIV  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV    yes  10713-234-NODIV
1                  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV     No             None
```

There can be more example like this, how to find out status and o/p value?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to use a loop. There are several options:

python ≥ 3.8:

```
import re
df['o/p value'] = [m if (m:=re.sub(f'^{re.escape(b)}\s*', '', a)) else float('nan')
                   for a,b in zip(df['col1'], df['Col2'])]

df['status'] = np.where(df['o/p value'].isna(), 'No', 'yes')
```

other versions:

```
import re
df['o/p value'] = [re.sub(f'^{re.escape(b)}\s*', '', a) for a,b in zip(df['col1'], df['Col2'])]

df['o/p value'] = df['o/p value'].mask(df['o/p value'].str.strip().eq(''))
df['status'] = np.where(df['o/p value'].isna(), 'No', 'yes')
```

output:

```
                                              col1                             Col2 status        o/p value
0  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV 10713-234-NODIV  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV    yes  10713-234-NODIV
1                  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV  10713-251-NODIV 10713-347-NODIV     No              NaN
```